# problem in parsing LTspice data

Tags: ltspice, python

I am using the ltspice python package to extract the data from the .raw file as seen in [this link](https://pypi.org/project/ltspice/). However, when I try to apply it to my raw file I get the following error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\ltspice\ltspice.py", line 98, in parse
    self.data_raw = np.reshape(np.array(self.data_raw), (self._point_num, self._variable_num + 1))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in reshape
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 301, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1746,33)*
```

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Best ask the creators of that package. This has very little to do with electronics.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I ended up finding the solution. The ltspice package for python should be updated. To anyone dealing with the same problem, better change the ltspice.py file with the one found [here](https://github.com/blubbrezn/ltspice_pytool/tree/master/ltspice)